# Problems installing latest version of jenkins

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

On my Ubuntu machine I am trying to do a local install of jenkins. I have followed this guide:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu

But when I run `sudo apt-get install jenkins` I get this error:

```
After this operation, 66.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 303314 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace jenkins 1.480.3+dfsg-1~exp2 (using .../archives/jenkins_1.535_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement jenkins ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/jenkins_1.535_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war', which is also in package jenkins-common 1.480.3+dfsg-1~exp2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
jenkins stop/waiting
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/jenkins_1.535_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It seems that an older installation is blocking the install. I have tried to delete:

```
/var/lib/jenkins
/usr/share/jenkins/
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to uninstall the old Jenkins version via the package manager, not just delete the files; I'm not sure what will happen now that you've deleted some files, but you can try

```
sudo apt-get purge jenkins
```

Then try the install again.

In future, you should be able to use

```
sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

to install a new version and keep your configuration from the old version.

Comment: Thanks @IgorGanapolsky , I fixed my answer.

Comment: This does not help me.  I got this error message from fresh install

Answer (score 2):

In my case(debian 7.0) this solution works well

```
$ mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/jenkins.* /tmp/
$ dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq jenkins
$ dpkg --purge jenkins
```

Comment: Tried this also does not help.  Got "installed jenkins package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1"

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to have Java installed first.

It worked after running:

```
$ sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre
$ sudo apt purge jenkins
$ sudo apt install jenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case openjdk-18 was installed and i need to remove it and installed openjdk-11

steps i followed:-

first check you have installed openjdk of any version.

```
apt list --installed | grep openjdk
```

If it is openjdk-11 only then it is fine.

If any other later version rather than openjdk-11 is installed, you need to remove it.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove openjdk-18-jre-headless
sudo apt-get autoremove openjdk-18-jdk-headless
```

Atlast install openjdk-11

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre
```

confirm openjdk-11 is on the path.

```
java --version
```