# Jenkins Install fails on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I followed the instructions in the answer to [Problems installing latest version of jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457867/problems-installing-latest-version-of-jenkins) but still seem to be getting the same error:

```
After this operation, 67.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 69476 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking jenkins (from .../archives/jenkins_1.552_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/jenkins_1.552_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war', which is also in package jenkins-common 1.424.6+dfsg-1ubuntu0.2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/jenkins_1.552_all.deb
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/ binary/ Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/pkg.jenkins-ci.org_debian_binary_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When running the purge command I now see the following so it seems like it was removed succesfully

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package jenkins is not installed, so not removed
...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
```

Comment: It says there you have a jenkins-common package already installed. Remove that first.

Comment: @nos, That worked. Thanks! Now to figure out why my plugin isn't working...